# How can I return a String value from a subframe to main frame through pushing a button in subframe

Tags: java, string, netbeans, actionlistener

I have created an actionListener for the button this is my code so far:

mainframe:

```
private class newItemListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent nN){
            String cmes = nN.getActionCommand();
            if (cmes=="New order"){
                NewOrder nor=new NewOrder();
                delArea.setText(nor.NewOrderAction());
            }
        }
}
```

The above code opens the subframe which is in the class NewOrder();

subframe:

```
 public class newOrderListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent nOL) {
            Object source = nOL.getSource();
            if (source==submitB){
                String appIDTX=appIDTF.getText();
                String orderIDTX=orderIDTF.getText();
                String orderDateTX=orderDateTF.getText();
                String clientNameTX=clientNameTF.getText();
                String itemNameTX=itemNameTF.getText();
                String unitsCountTX=unitsCountTF.getText();
                String netItemPriceTX=netItemPriceTF.getText();
                String taxPercentageTX=taxPercentageTF.getText();
                    temp=appIDTX+";"+orderIDTX+";"+orderDateTX+";"+clientNameTX+";"+itemNameTX+";"
                            +unitsCountTX+";"+netItemPriceTX+";"+taxPercentageTX;

            }
        }
    }
```

In the above code is only the actionListener of the button I push in the subframe.

So have any idea how I can return String temp in the main frame?Sorry if its obvious and my question is stupid.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Call a method in the main frame class and pass the text to it.

Comment: But the text will be produced in the actionListener which is void how im supposed to retun it

Comment: In the actionListener, add a call to a method in the main frame class that passes the value.